# Cant use two different table view cell in one view cell

Tags: swift, parse-platform, tableview, uitableview

I take data from parsing and put them into table views (think posts). In my app, there are posts that users share; some of them have images, some of them not. I want to make two different view cells, such that one of them has Image View and the other does not.

But, I have trouble when I set the data. If there is not an Image in the post during parsing, I get a nil exception. How to I solve that problem and make them in different views?

This is where I get the data from parsing:

```
 if let objects = objects {
     for object in objects {
         let titles = object["titleOfPost"] as! String
         self.postTitles.append(titles)
         let messages = object["messageOfPost"] as! String
         self.postMessages.append(messages)

         if (object["imageOfPost"] != nil) {
             let feedImageFile:PFFile = object["imageOfPost"] as! PFFile
             feedImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData, error) -> Void in
                 if (imageData != nil) {
                     self.postImages.append(UIImage(data:imageData!)!)
                 }
             })
         }
    }
}
```

And this is the code that I use in table view:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TextViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TextPostTableViewCell

    cell.titleOfPost.text = postTitles[postTitles.count - indexPath.row-1]
    cell.messageOfPost.text = postMessages[postMessages.count - indexPath.row-1]
    cell.username.text = "osman"
    cell.profileImage.image = UIImage(named:"icon_ios_user")
    cell.email.text = "email@email.com"

    return cell
}
```

How can I solve the data problem and then put 2 different view cells in just one table view, sorting by the time of sharing post?

Comment: Use a simple if statement to deque different cells. Covered in thousands of example codes.

Comment: I would not recommend your force-unwrapping code

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an if statement to check if the image exists, something like :

```
 if let image = dictData.objectForKey("Image"){
            cell.imageView?.image = image as? UIImage
        }
```

If you need to show 2 completely different cells in the table then create the custom cells, giving them unique reuse identifiers and register in viewDidLoad :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Custom Cell with Image
    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomCellImage", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCellImage")

    // Custom Cell with Text
    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomCellText", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellText")

}
```

Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath select the cell to use on whatever condition:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let dictData : NSDictionary = arrayOfData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary

    let strTypeObject = dictData.objectForKey("ObjectType") as! String


    if strTypeObject == "ImageType"
    {
        let cell: CustomCellImage = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCellImage", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCellImage
        cell.lblImageText.text = dictData.objectForKey("ObjectMessage") as? String
        cell.customImageView.image = dictData.objectForKey("Image") as? UIImage
        return cell
    }

    if strTypeObject == "StringType"
    {
        let cell: CustomCellText = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellText", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCellText
        cell.lblJustSomeText.text = dictData.objectForKey("ObjectMessage") as? String
        return cell
    }


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = dictData.objectForKey("ObjectMessage") as? String
    if let image = dictData.objectForKey("Image"){
        cell.imageView?.image = image as? UIImage
    }
    return cell
}
```